# Problems with adding JPanel into JLayer

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, jlayer

I am currently working on a Java Swing application. I want to use a `JLayer` to decorate a `JPanel` but get stuck.

Now I am going to add a `JTextArea` into a `JPanel` and then add the `JPanel` into a `JLayer`, and finally into a `JScrollPane`. A `JPanel` is a must because I want to add extra component beside the `JTextArea` (The `JTextArea` will be added to `BorderLayout.CENTER` and the custom component, `BorderLayout.LINE_START`). The problem is that `JPanel` does not expand automatically but shrinks to (0, 0) size.

I have thought of some workarounds but they aren't quite suitable.

(1) Add a `JScrollPane` into to the `JLayer` and add the `JLayer` into the top-level container directly. However the `JLayer` also covers the `JScrollPane` while I only want it to cover the `JTextArea`.

(2) Avoid using a `JPanel` and look for other ways to add a custom component beside the `JTextArea`, but I couldn't think of any simple way to achieve it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                //add JLayer
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("JTextArea blah blah blah");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JLayer<JPanel> layer = new JLayer<JPanel>(panel, new LayerUI<JPanel>());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(layer), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                //setup frame and show
                frame.setSize(250,250);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

My workaround (1):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                //add JLayer
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("JTextArea blah blah blah");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                JLayer<JScrollPane> layer = new JLayer<JScrollPane>(new JScrollPane(panel), new LayerUI<JScrollPane>());
                frame.add(layer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                //setup frame and show
                frame.setSize(250,250);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This seems to work but the `JLayer` painting will cover the `JScrollPane`'s scroll bar which is not preferred.

(Example of covering the `JScrollPane`: subclass `LayerUI`:)

```
new LayerUI<JScrollPane>()
{
      @Override
      public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c)
      {
            super.paint(g,c);
            g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0,50));
            g.fillRect(0,0,c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
      }
}
```

on scrolling (`JScrollPane` covered by `JLayer`):

[image]

So how to achieve a correct result? Thanks for solutions in advance.

Comment: So your problem is that the `JPanel` is not expanding? Have you tried using a different layout?

Comment: I can't call setLayout(new BorderLayout()) on a JLayer

Comment: You could clip the painting in the layer to the region not contain the scroll bars

Comment: I know, but I would prefer figuring out why my code doesn't work as expected. Also it is not a very elegant approach. =)